# JLabel action Listener in Java

Tags: java, actionlistener, jlabel

I wanna get inform from data base and after click to get JOption window with notification....Is it possible to add action listenr for JLabel when it is created dynamically? if yes then HOW?
Here is my code..........

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
public class DBConnect {
    public Connection con;
    public Statement st;
    public ResultSet rs;
    public DBConnect() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "");
            st = con.createStatement();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error " + ex);
        }
    }
    public void getData() {
        try {
            String query = "select * from persons";
            rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            System.out.println("Records from database\n");
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("panel demo");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                    Container c = frame.getContentPane();
                    panel.setSize(100, 100);
                    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1000, 1));
                    try {
                        while (rs.next()) {
                            try {
                                String name = rs.getString("Name");
                                panel.add(new JLabel("JLabel " + name));
                            } catch (SQLException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(panel);
                    c.add(jsp);
                    frame.setSize(100, 100);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error " + ex);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        DBConnect a = new DBConnect();
        a.getData();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is unfortunately no possibility to add an `ActionListener` to a `JLabel`.

---

It is definitely possible to dynamically add an `ActionListener` to another component (e.g `JButton`). For that, you could use the anonymous class one or create a separate class that implements `ActionListener` and use it in your code.

Comment: But then my scroll doesn't work can you correct may code please?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a MouseListener to your JLabel and then define a behavior for "click" or whatever you want.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html on how to implement mouse listeners.

Mathias